# Alexa SpeechletResponse must not be null

Tags: python, alexa-skills-kit

I have the following code handling the `ResumeIntent` on Alexa.

```
if intent == "AMAZON.ResumelIntent":
    return {
        "version": "1.0",
        "sessionAttributes": {},
        "response": {
        "outputSpeech": {               
            "type": "PlainText",
            "text": "Resuming"
            },
            "directives": [
                {
                    "type": "AudioPlayer.Play"
                }
            ],
            "shouldEndSession": True
        }
    }
```

I initially didn't have `outputSpeech` there but added it after reading a forum thread that said it needed to be at the minimum an empty dictionary.

I also tried having it as

```
if intent == "AMAZON.PauseIntent":
    return {
        "response": {
            "directives": [
            {
                "type": "AudioPlayer.Stop",
                    "playBehavior": "REPLACE_ALL",
                    "audioItem": {
                        "stream": {
                            "token": "12345",
                            "url": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/jingle.mp3",
                            "offsetInMilliseconds": 0
                        }
            }
            ],
            "shouldEndSession": True
        }
    }
```

However every single time Alexa gives me the `Null SpeechletResponse` error.

I'm testing the Skill on my Fire tablet.

Answer (score 0):

Bloody typo

`AMAZON.ResumelIntent`

Should've been

`AMAZON.ResumeIntent`